# Understanding what a factor is in a model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a model which I built with a number of factors as fixed effect variables. Up to now they all had two values e.g. high tide/low tide and so when I ran the summary it would show one variance for the variable (but it had a 2 next to those coded as an as.factor). After suddenly running a fixed effect with four IDs (Tide level) I had a duh moment and realised that the value shown is the effect for the second ID and now of course the third and fourth. The issue is I wanted to interpret the results as shown in this results table:

```
Table 3. Model-averaged parameter estimates and relative importance
values for variables affecting adult piping plover foraging rates in New Jersey,
2007–2009.
Parameter         Estimate          95% CI
Intercept           11.78         10.07 13.49
Habitat
    Intertidal      3.97          2.45   5.49
    Wrack           1.37          0.46   3.20
    Ephemeral pool  2.65          4.62   9.92
    Tidal pond      5.52          3.84   7.20
    Bay shore       2.32          0.03   4.61
    Sand flat       2.30          4.34   0.26
Tidal stage
    Low             3.98          3.05   4.91
    High            1.62          1.36   4.60
Wind speed          0.01          0.02   0.04
```

Note that it states that it shows the relative importance values too but I don't see them. Obviously they had run a model something like this Foraging Rate~Habitat+Tide Level+Wind Speed + (1|Site)
The major issue is how do I get an effect value for the first category within a variable (i.e. 'Tide 1') (and Low tide or Intertidal in the above example)
I can give you an example of my results here:

```
> testm1<-lmer(Feeding~Age+Tide+mean.catch.rate+mean.for.rate+(1|Brood), data=ABMnoD, REML=FALSE)
> testm1
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
Formula: Feeding ~ Age + Tide + mean.catch.rate + mean.for.rate + (1 |      Brood) 
   Data: ABMnoD 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 350.3 366.1 -166.1    332.3   312.5
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Brood    (Intercept)   0.00    0.00   
 Residual             132.93   11.53   
Number of obs: 43, groups: Brood, 7

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)      94.05421    5.76798  16.306
Age              -0.38108    0.31678  -1.203
Tide2             2.01871    5.38376   0.375
Tide3            -4.42228    5.34896  -0.827
Tide4           -13.03191    5.54832  -2.349
mean.catch.rate   0.88214    1.66752   0.529
mean.for.rate    -0.09334    1.13695  -0.082

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Age    Tide2  Tide3  Tide4  mn.ct.
Age         -0.282                                   
Tide2       -0.433 -0.133                            
Tide3       -0.314 -0.189  0.514                     
Tide4       -0.308 -0.405  0.510  0.558              
men.ctch.rt  0.072 -0.205  0.280  0.423  0.347       
mean.for.rt -0.236  0.070 -0.218 -0.386 -0.260 -0.956
```

As I have been running a dredge to find the best fit models I would also end up with results in the following format from model.avg

```
Component models:
   df  logLik   AICc Delta Weight
3   6 -167.43 349.19  0.00   0.55
13  7 -166.86 350.92  1.72   0.23
23  7 -166.90 351.00  1.80   0.22

Term codes:
mean.catch.rate   mean.for.rate            Tide 
              1               2               3 

Model-averaged coefficients: 
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      94.6299     5.0785  18.633  < 2e-16 ***
Tide2             0.3714     5.2833   0.070 0.943965    
Tide3            -6.1620     4.9492   1.245 0.213109    
Tide4           -16.4001     4.9791   3.294 0.000989 ***
mean.catch.rate   0.4728     0.4387   1.078 0.281208    
mean.for.rate     0.3170     0.3052   1.039 0.298933    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Full model-averaged coefficients (with shrinkage): 
 (Intercept)      Tide2      Tide3      Tide4 mean.catch.rate mean.for.rate
   94.629898   0.371350  -6.162041 -16.400131        0.109312      0.070415

Relative variable importance:
    (Intercept)             Age mean.catch.rate   mean.for.rate            Tide 
           1.00            0.00            0.23            0.22            1.00
```

and the confidence intervals:

```
> confint(avgmodD2)
                      2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)      84.6762427 104.5835534
Tide2            -9.9837967  10.7264976
Tide3           -15.8622641   3.5381824
Tide4           -26.1590703  -6.6411917
mean.catch.rate  -0.3870958   1.3326081
mean.for.rate    -0.2811417   0.9151314
```

I am just not sure how to get the values for the first group from each categorical fixed effect and if the rest of the values e.g for Tide3 need to be adjusted in relation. I just cannot find any paperwork on how to do this.

I appreciate of someone could spend a little time to explain this to me.

Thank you.

Rachel

Ammendment in response to answer by jbowman:

I ran all four options:
With and without intercept then these with the y adjustment. The Relative Importance of each factor stayed the same in each:

Regular model average with no removal of intercept

```
Model-averaged coefficients: 
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  98.3228     4.5234  21.736  < 2e-16 ***
Tide2             -0.1183     5.4797   0.022  0.98277    
Tide3             -5.9914     5.2249   1.147  0.25151    
Tide4             -16.2022     5.2832   3.067  0.00216 ** 
MF.vs.OF2    -6.1143     4.5997   1.329  0.18376    

Full model-averaged coefficients (with shrinkage): 
 (Intercept)     Tide2     Tide3     Tide4 MF.vs.OF2
    98.32281  -0.11833  -5.99141 -16.20216  -2.37172
```

Without intercept:

```
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Tide1       96.742      3.601  26.866   <2e-16 ***
Tide2       59.097     47.373   1.247    0.212    
Tide3       53.224     46.893   1.135    0.256    
Tide4       43.014     46.626   0.923    0.356    
MF.vs.OF1  100.818      4.703  21.436   <2e-16 ***
MF.vs.OF2   94.704      3.882  24.398   <2e-16 ***

Full model-averaged coefficients (with shrinkage): 
  Tide1  Tide2  Tide3  Tide4 MF.vs.OF1 MF.vs.OF2
 59.216 59.097 53.224 43.014    39.107    36.735
```

With y removed but still with intercept:

```
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   7.5223     4.5234   1.663  0.09632 . 
Tide2        -0.1183     5.4797   0.022  0.98277   
Tide3        -5.9914     5.2249   1.147  0.25151   
Tide4       -16.2022     5.2832   3.067  0.00216 **
MF.vs.OF2    -6.1143     4.5997   1.329  0.18376   

Full model-averaged coefficients (with shrinkage): 
 (Intercept)     Tide2     Tide3     Tide4 MF.vs.OF2
     7.52235  -0.11833  -5.99141 -16.20216  -2.37172
```

And lastly with y mean removed (with Intercept also removed):

```
Model-averaged coefficients: 
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
Tide1        5.941      3.601   1.650   0.0990 .
Tide2        3.518      5.520   0.637   0.5239  
Tide3       -2.355      5.013   0.470   0.6385  
Tide4      -12.566      4.917   2.556   0.0106 *
MF.vs.OF1   10.017      4.703   2.130   0.0332 *
MF.vs.OF2    3.903      3.882   1.006   0.3146  

Full model-averaged coefficients (with shrinkage): 
    Tide1    Tide2    Tide3    Tide4 MF.vs.OF1 MF.vs.OF2
   3.6366   3.5183  -2.3548 -12.5655    3.8857    1.5140
```

Note p-values change with each but RVIs do not. Not sure how to continue and which I should use. Could I calculate the Intercept and relative Estimates from these values?
Thank you.

Comment: I would also like to apologise for so many questions over the past week, but I really feel that I am learning so much where books have failed me. I have resolved many of them and now assume that the reason that PIVs don't always correlate with the Estimates is because I wasn't taking the first estimate that is unseen into account. Therefore the answer to this question would really solve any remaining issues that I have had. THANK YOU all.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask `lmer` not to estimate an intercept, it's smart enough to realize this means you must want the absolute, rather than relative, factor estimates (some of the output below has been removed to save space).  You should probably center the dependent variable before running the model without an intercept, as is done in the code below.

```
> library(lme4)
> 
> # Construct sample data
> x <- as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10))
> z <- as.factor(rep(c("D","E","F","G","H"),6))
> y <- rnorm(30, as.numeric(x))
> 
> 
> # Run model with intercept: gives relative effects
> summary(lmer(y~x+(1|z)))
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: y ~ x + (1 | z) 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 92.76 99.77 -41.38    81.12   82.76
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 z        (Intercept) 0.00000  0.00000 
 Residual             0.97188  0.98584 
Number of obs: 30, groups: z, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   1.5572     0.3118   4.995
xB            0.4971     0.4409   1.128
xC            1.1541     0.4409   2.618

> # Run model w/o intercept: gives absolute effects
> # First center y so no confounding of intercept with effects
> y <- scale(y, scale=FALSE)
> summary(lmer(y~x+(1|z)-1))
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: y ~ x + (1 | z) - 1 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 92.76 99.77 -41.38    81.12   82.76
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 z        (Intercept) 0.00000  0.00000 
 Residual             0.97188  0.98584 
Number of obs: 30, groups: z, 5

Fixed effects:
   Estimate Std. Error t value
xA -0.55042    0.31175  -1.766
xB -0.05329    0.31175  -0.171
xC  0.60371    0.31175   1.937
```

Otherwise the factor estimates have to be relative (although not necessarily relative to the first factor), as with an intercept present, the factors and intercept together are perfectly multicollinear.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly. I thought everyone had sighed and been scared off by my relentless questions.
Will this also work if I put the -1 in the global model and the dredge it and perform model.avg? Again, thank you.

Comment: okay, I ran a model. the issue is with model.avg is it giving me different outputs. It just gives me the IDs of the component models and the coefficients for each category. the Estimates of the global model are also high so are the coefficients in this case the same as the Estimates. Does it look bad to have Coef close to 100? I have also lost the 'weights' output for the factors.

Comment: Well, don't forget, since you're taking out the intercept, the "average" coefficient of a factor will be adjusted to make up for that.  In your second block of code in the question,  I notice an intercept of 94.05, so I'm not surprised if one or more of the coefficients is close to 100.  If you don't like that, you can always record the mean of `y` then subtract it off before running the model; the weighted (by frequency) average of the factor coefficients will then equal zero, and you can add the mean back in for estimation / prediction of `y`.

Comment: The only issue is that I don't know how to do that. I DID just run it again and it gave me estimates (albeit Tide 1 is pretty high and one is above 100. Feeding is based on a percentage and there are some that are up to 100 so perhaps it is okay. I have the results of both options but cannot post for another three hours. However everything is the same except for the Estimates (i.e. AICc of each model, the PIVs. Also, the p-values have changed, but are these usually published or is it okay to just compare the estimates and the PIVs? I also assume that the bigger estimates mean that they

Comment: These are the results from that without the intercept:

Comment: `Model-averaged coefficients: 
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Tide1       96.742      3.601  26.866   <2e-16 ***
Tide2       59.097     47.373   1.247    0.212    
Tide3       53.224     46.893   1.135    0.256    
Tide4       43.014     46.626   0.923    0.356    
MF.vs.OF1  100.818      4.703  21.436   <2e-16 ***
MF.vs.OF2   94.704      3.882  24.398   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Relative variable importance:
     Age MF.vs.OF     Site     Tide 
    0.00     0.39     0.00     1.00`

Comment: And with the intercept:

Comment: `(Intercept)  98.3228     4.5234  21.736  < 2e-16 ***
Tide2        -0.1183     5.4797   0.022  0.98277    
Tide3        -5.9914     5.2249   1.147  0.25151    
Tide4       -16.2022     5.2832   3.067  0.00216 ** 
MF.vs.OF2    -6.1143     4.5997   1.329  0.18376    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 `

Comment: because I have never interpreted these results to put into a paper I was basing some of it on the paper. I am not sure how I would interpret this, but could I just say that Tide one has the greatest effect on the time spent feeding. My issue is interpreting the p-values. Am I able to state that Tide one has a significant effect and would I graph the values to see if it is a positive or negative effect? Should I even use the term 'significant'? And why would significance differ when everything else, such as weights and AICs etc not changed? I am sorry that I don't understand all the intracacies

Comment: Basically, this is how the paper used the data:

Comment: Of the 5 habitats in which we observed
plovers feeding, effect size was highest at artificial tidal ponds
(5.52), followed by the intertidal zone (3.97). Positive effects
of ephemeral pools (2.65) and bay shores (2.32) on adult
foraging rates were 48% and 42% lower than artificial ponds,
respectively. Conversely, sand flats (2.30) had an equal but
opposite effect on foraging rate, when compared to bay
shores. The results also indicated that foraging rate was
highest for adults during the post-breeding stage.

Comment: In addition,
vehicles had a 2.3 times larger effect on foraging adults
than people. Finally, foraging rates during low tide were
higher than at high tide by a factor of 2.5, as would be
expected.

Comment: As you can see they are able to use the Estimates with positive and negative estimates in a very clear manner, which is what I was excited about when I got the original estimates with similar patterns of positive and negative, but they have all the estimates AND an intercept so I don't know how they did this.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how the centering works and its effect.  It will take me a little while before I can go over all your comments :)

Comment: You are amazing to be helping this way. If I can fix this then I don't see anything else stopping me.

Comment: (I know I keep saying that)
I am just wondering how they managed to get both Intercept AND Estimates. Do you think that they did it the normal way and then used the Intercept from this first run and then got the estimates with your second method? 
I assume that you would then add the mean back in (I am not sure whether that would be the overall mean of Y or the mean for only when that factor level is present. Is this a presentable method or just trying to get it the way I want without reason?
However, I await with patience for your additional comments. I understand that you must be very busy.

Comment: Dragon, jbowman, please continue this conversation in a chat room.

Comment: @whuber, I do not know how to go into chat. I have added the new info to the bottom of my question, but edited out a lot of the repeated data so it should be clearer. thank you.